# System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. ( Openvpn )

Tags: debian, openvpn, terminal-server, terminal, debian-buster

I'm pretty new to Linux and i'm still learning the ropes of it.
I tried starting the openvpn service using both "systemd start openvpn@server" and "sudo systemctl start openvpn@server" but I still got the error "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate."
I still can't understand the problem since I booted with systemd.
Any ideas are welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: Exactly what is your system?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yea I kinda forgot that -__-
I run Linux 4.19.0.17-amd64 SMP Debian 4.19.194-2 X86_64 GNU/Linux
Also I'll mention that I did the system update first

Comment: That's your kernel version? What about the rest of the system? What is the hardware? Tell everything. Do not wait to be asked.

Comment: @MichaelHampton 
 bus    Lancer 5A6
  memory      64KiB BIOS
processor   Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2830  @ 2.16GHz
 memory   32KiB L1 cache
memory   1MiB L2 cache
  memory   24KiB L1 cache 
bridge      Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1
  bridge      Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3
   RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
  Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4
  network   RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
kernel release: 4.19.0-17-amd64
kernel ver: #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-2 (2021-06-21)
 hardware: x86_64

Comment: Interesting. So what exactly is PID 1? Run `ps 1 | cat`

Comment: that's what I also wanna know lol 
it gives me this 
 PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:02 init [5]

Comment: Exactly what Linux distribution did you install on this old computer and how did you install it?

Comment: It's MX Linux and I installed it from a USB and booted it through BIOS

Comment: Well that's a bizarre choice. Did you read their [documentation](https://mxlinux.org/wiki/system/systemd/)?  MX Linux doesn't actually use systemd by default.

Comment: I read it but not throughout the entire thing. I'll read it and see if I can find a solution to this. I used systemd as my last hope but didn't know that MX doesn't use it. Anyway, thanks for lending a hand on this topic ^_^